# How to remove overlap of objects in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe

I've tried every option in the Pathfinder tool. No luck there. I have a red bar overtop an icon that has a circle as a background. I'd like to remove the sections of the red bar that overlap the circle. The objects are on the same layer, and I'm selecting the circle and the red bar before I click on the various Pathfinder options.

Any suggestions as to what mistake I'm making? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcMi1.png)

Comment: I figured it out. "Minus Back" in Pathfinder works. The reason I didn't see it when I first chose Minus Back is that I assumed ALL the overlapping sections would be deleted automatically. Minus Back just cuts them into new objects. You have to select them and delete them. Another reason I didn't see the result of the action is that I wasn't zoomed in close enough to notice that MB had cut new paths. 

It pays to be zoomed in at the overlap when you're using Pathfinder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer noted above:

I figured it out. "Minus Back" in Pathfinder works. The reason I didn't see it when I first chose Minus Back is that I assumed ALL the overlapping sections would be deleted automatically. Minus Back just cuts them into new objects. You have to select them and delete them. Another reason I didn't see the result of the action is that I wasn't zoomed in close enough to notice that MB had cut new paths. It pays to be zoomed in at the overlap when you're using Pathfinder.